# Basic Jquery Slider(bjqs) not working with one slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, bjqs

My basic `Jquery slider(bjqs)` not working after I give only one li element...the result not displaying what I put in li tag....it working perfectly after if I put 4 li elements.

What are the problems going on here?

4 `li` (working fine) : link(http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/DaXG7/9/)

```
    <article class="salon_cvrs" id="banner-fade">                       
                            <ul class="bjqs">
                                <li>
                                    <article class="saloon-box">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="saloon-box">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="saloon-box">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                    </article>
                                    <article class="saloon-box">
                                        <article class="featured">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                    </article>
                                </li>

                            <li>
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article>
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                    <p>Everyone loves an effortless hairstyle that also hints at glamour. And an easy up-do that doesn't feel too 'done' is exactly the way to go to create it. </p>
                                </article>
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article>
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                    <article class="featured">
                                            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                        </article>
```

Only one `li` (not-working) : (http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/xD4FL/9/)

```
<article class="salon_cvrs" id="banner-fade">                       
                        <ul class="bjqs">
                            <li>
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article>    
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article> 
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article> 
                                <article class="saloon-box">
                                        <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."</p>
                                </article>                        
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </article>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the script you have doesn't change the layout when only one item is provided as a slide. And the fact that it disappears is because of your own styles

```
li.bjqs-slide{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

If you change `display: none` to say `display: block` or `inline-block` - the slide will be shown